# Python3: **TypeError: string indices must be integers **

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have written the following function:

```py
def get_metric_data(start_time, end_time, query, resolution, max_length):
    '''
    Retrieves prometheus metric data and returns a pd.Series
    
        Parameters:
                start_time (string): x start time in seconds (s), minutes (m), hours (h), or days (d) 
                end_time (string): x end time in seconsd (s), minutes (m), hours (h), days (d), or now
                query (string): a PromQL query
                resolution (float): time interval width in seconds, e.g., 1.00 = 1 second width
                max_length (int): will ensure returned data is of fixed-length
        Returns:
                metric_data (pandas.Series): A pandas Series object containing the time series

        Usage: 
            get_metric_data("5m", "now", "rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[1m])", 1.00
    '''

    #Specify time interval
    datetime_start = parse_datetime(start_time)
    datetime_end = parse_datetime(end_time)

    #Query prometheus 
    metric_df = MetricRangeDataFrame(prom.custom_query_range(query, datetime_start, datetime_end, 1.00))
    return metric_df["value"].reset_index().drop("timestamp",axis=1).T.squeeze().tail(max_length)

def get_injection_status(chaos_type, namespace, experiment_name):
    '''
    Retrieves the status of a Chaos Mesh experiment and returns 1 if injection is in progress or 0 if not.
    
        Parameters:
            chaos_type (string): the type of Chaos Mesh injection (e.g., stresschaos)
            namespace (string): the Kubernetes namespace where the experiment was being conducted
            experiment_name: the name of the Chaos Mesh experiment

        Returns:
            injection_status (int): 1 if injection in progress, 0 if injection is paused or completed

        Usage:
            get_injection_status("stresschaos", "wordpress", "my-experiment-1")

    '''

    with kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
        api_instance = kubernetes.client.CustomObjectsApi(api_client)
        group = "chaos-mesh.org"
        version = "v1alpha1"
        plural = "stresschaos"
        name = experiment_name
        namespace = "wordpress"


        api_response = api_instance.get_namespaced_custom_object(group, version, namespace, plural, name)
        experiment_status =  api_response['status']['experiment']['containerRecords'][0]['phase']
        return 1 if experiment_status == 'Injected' else 0

def get_labelled_panel_metric_data(start_time, end_time, query, resolution, max_length, duration, interval, 
                                    chaos_type, namespace, experiment_name):
    '''
    Retrieves Prometheus metric data and returns a "nested_univ" time series panel. Current version supports univariate (single) time series panel.
    
        Parameters:
                start_time (string): x start time in seconds (s), minutes (m), hours (h), or days (d) 
                end_time (string): x end time in seconsd (s), minutes (m), hours (h), days (d), or now
                query (string): a PromQL query
                resolution (float): time interval width in seconds, e.g., 1.00 = 1 second width
                max_length (int): will ensure returned data is of fixed-length
                instances
                duration (int): time in seconds to collect data
                interval (int): the time in seconds to collect between instances
                chaos_type (string): the type of Chaos Mesh injection (e.g., stresschaos)
                namespace (string): the Kubernetes namespace where the experiment was being conducted
                experiment_name: the name of the Chaos Mesh experiment
        Returns:
                panel_data ("nested_univ"): A pandas.DataFrame time series panel conforming to "nested_univ" sktime mtype
                y_list (pd.Series) : a pandas.Series of class labels

        Usage:
                x, y = get_labelled_panel_metric_data(...)
    '''

    x_list = []
    y_list = []

    for i in range(duration):
        x_list.append(get_metric_data(start_time, end_time, query, resolution, max_length))
        y_list.append(get_injection_status(chaos_type, namespace, experiment_name))
        sleep(interval)

    panel_data = pd.DataFrame({'dim_0': x_list})
    
    return panel_data, pd.Series(y_list)
```

When I try to call the function "get_injection_status" throgh the code below, I receive this error:

```py
token_path= './work/token.json'
kubernetes_url = 'https://192.168.39.81:8443'
client_cert_path = './work/client.crt'

f = open(token_path)
token_json = json.load(f)
bearer_token = token_json['status']['token']
configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
configuration.api_key["authorization"] = bearer_token
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
configuration.host = kubernetes_url
configuration.verify_ssl=False
configuration.ssl_ca_cert = client_cert_path


start_time = "5m"
end_time ="now"
query = 'rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="my-release-wordpress-6dc6484885-bbj2q"}[1m])*100'
resolution=1.00
max_length = 300
duration = 900
interval = 1
chaos_type = "stresschaos"
namespace = "wordpress"
experiment_name = "itec-experiment-cpu-stress-4"

df = get_metric_data(start_time, end_time, query, resolution, max_length=300)
get_injection_status("stresschaos", "wordpress", "itec-experiment-cpu-stress-4")
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_12604/1433600732.py in <module>
     18 display(af)
     19 #df = get_metric_data(start_time, end_time, query, resolution, max_length=300)
---> 20 get_injection_status("stresschaos", "robot-shop", "fault-3")
     21 #X, y = get_labelled_panel_metric_data(start_time, end_time, query, resolution, max_length, duration, interval,chaos_type,namespace, experiment_name)
/tmp/ipykernel_12604/1838233100.py in get_injection_status(chaos_type, namespace, experiment_name)
     52         api_response = api_instance.get_namespaced_custom_object(group, version, namespace, plural, name)
     53
---> 54         experiment_status =  api_response['status']['experiment']['containerRecords'][0]['phase']
     55         return 1 if experiment_status == 'Injected' else 0
     56
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am sure that get_injection_status should be string and it should not take integers. I have no clue what am I getting this error.

Could you please enlighten me on this?

Thank you.

The function shoulld be passed because it is string and the inputs are string

Comment: The stacktrace tells you exactly where you are getting that error have you tried looking at it? Also send it over here so that we see it too, the last line of the stack trace which is just the exception is not that helpful without the other lines of the traceback.

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error.  Without it, we can only guess, and no one wants to go through every single line of your code looking for what you already have.

Comment: is `api_response` a string? is `api_response["status"]` a string? is `api_response['status']['experiment']` a string? is `api_response['status']['experiment']['containerRecords'][0]` a string?